# Autogen's human input reloads server

Tags: python, autogen

So, basically I am using [NiceGui](https://nicegui.io/) to create a UI over `AutoGen`. I have set the `human_input_mode` to `ALWAYS`. Whenever `Autogen` asks for the human input, the server reloads and the conversation is lost. `reload=False` doesn't work.

`ui.run(title='Chat with Autogen Assistant', on_air=True,reload=False` (same behaviour on `localhost` just to clarify.

```
def check_termination_and_human_reply(
        self,
        messages: Optional[List[Dict]] = None,
        sender: Optional[Agent] = None,
        config: Optional[Any] = None,
    ) -> Tuple[bool, Union[str, None]]:
        """Check if the conversation should be terminated, and if human reply is provided.

        This method checks for conditions that require the conversation to be terminated, such as reaching
        a maximum number of consecutive auto-replies or encountering a termination message. Additionally,
        it prompts for and processes human input based on the configured human input mode, which can be
        'ALWAYS', 'NEVER', or 'TERMINATE'. The method also manages the consecutive auto-reply counter
        for the conversation and prints relevant messages based on the human input received.

        Args:
            - messages (Optional[List[Dict]]): A list of message dictionaries, representing the conversation history.
            - sender (Optional[Agent]): The agent object representing the sender of the message.
            - config (Optional[Any]): Configuration object, defaults to the current instance if not provided.

        Returns:
            - Tuple[bool, Union[str, Dict, None]]: A tuple containing a boolean indicating if the conversation
            should be terminated, and a human reply which can be a string, a dictionary, or None.
        """
        # Function implementation...

        if config is None:
            config = self
        if messages is None:
            messages = self._oai_messages[sender]
        message = messages[-1]
        reply = ""
        no_human_input_msg = ""
        if self.human_input_mode == "ALWAYS":
            reply = self.get_human_input(
                f"Provide feedback to {sender.name}. Press enter to skip and use auto-reply, or type 'exit' to end the conversation: "
            )
            no_human_input_msg = "NO HUMAN INPUT RECEIVED." if not reply else ""
            # if the human input is empty, and the message is a termination message, then we will terminate the conversation
            reply = reply if reply or not self._is_termination_msg(message) else "exit"
        else:
            if self._consecutive_auto_reply_counter[sender] >= self._max_consecutive_auto_reply_dict[sender]:
                if self.human_input_mode == "NEVER":
                    reply = "exit"
                else:
                    # self.human_input_mode == "TERMINATE":
                    terminate = self._is_termination_msg(message)
                    reply = self.get_human_input(
                        f"Please give feedback to {sender.name}. Press enter or type 'exit' to stop the conversation: "
                        if terminate
                        else f"Please give feedback to {sender.name}. Press enter to skip and use auto-reply, or type 'exit' to stop the conversation: "
                    )
                    no_human_input_msg = "NO HUMAN INPUT RECEIVED." if not reply else ""
                    # if the human input is empty, and the message is a termination message, then we will terminate the conversation
                    reply = reply if reply or not terminate else "exit"
            elif self._is_termination_msg(message):
                if self.human_input_mode == "NEVER":
                    reply = "exit"
                else:
                    # self.human_input_mode == "TERMINATE":
                    reply = self.get_human_input(
                        f"Please give feedback to {sender.name}. Press enter or type 'exit' to stop the conversation: "
                    )
                    no_human_input_msg = "NO HUMAN INPUT RECEIVED." if not reply else ""
                    # if the human input is empty, and the message is a termination message, then we will terminate the conversation
                    reply = reply or "exit"

        # print the no_human_input_msg
        if no_human_input_msg:
            print(colored(f"\n>>>>>>>> {no_human_input_msg}", "red"), flush=True)

        # stop the conversation
        if reply == "exit":
            # reset the consecutive_auto_reply_counter
            self._consecutive_auto_reply_counter[sender] = 0
            return True, None

        # send the human reply
        if reply or self._max_consecutive_auto_reply_dict[sender] == 0:
            # reset the consecutive_auto_reply_counter
            self._consecutive_auto_reply_counter[sender] = 0
            return True, reply

        # increment the consecutive_auto_reply_counter
        self._consecutive_auto_reply_counter[sender] += 1
        if self.human_input_mode != "NEVER":
            print(colored("\n>>>>>>>> USING AUTO REPLY...", "red"), flush=True)

        return False, None
```

Not sure what is causing it and how to solve this.

Comment: Please clarify to us, upon server reload, whether you notice any error messages or logs; these can provide crucial hints.

Comment: Nothing appears in the terminal except `Provide feedback to chat_manager. Press enter to skip and use auto-reply, or type 'exit' to end the conversation: ` , debug=True, in ui.run is also an invalid paramter

Comment: and one more clarification as well, I am not really sure what you're trying to solve here, it's not clear, is it unwanted server reload or is it preserving conversations?

Comment: The issue is , that if the server refreshes, all UI elements do, so the chat messages are gone, yes I'd like to preserve the conversation if I take it that the UI behaviour will remain like this , then need to explore other options, I was hoping it could be avoided in NiceGUI itself

Answer (score 1):

From conclusions based on conversation within comments:
In web-based applications, like yours here, especially those which are using server-side frameworks like `Flask` (which `NiceGui` does use "under the hood"), because HTTP is stateless, it might be difficult to preserve state across requests. Because each request is distinct, server-side programs are not predisposed to "remember" prior exchanges.

So, possible solutions:

**Using session variables** - Consider if it fits your needs, and the security concerns and the amount of data saved in sessions.

**File or database-based state persistence** - it would involve updating; each time the user interacts, update the state in the database or file.

**Websockets** - With WebSockets, client and server can communicate in both directions without refreshing the page. (I am not sure if NiceGui supports it, so you'd need to confirm that).

**READ:** Alright, I ended up giving false information for some reason I was convinced that NiceGUI is using Flask for some reason, as stated in comments **NiceGUI doesn't use Flask, but FastAPI**. Still the part of the answer about HTTP being stateless applies to web applications in general, including those built with FastAPI.

Comment: As far as I understand, Abhishek is trying to disable the auto-reload feature which restarts the server as soon as a file is changed. See https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/2339 for a discussion on the very same problem. But I still have more question than answers.
By the way: NiceGUI uses FastAPI, not Flask. 

Comment: @Falko I was struggling with both. Auto-reload somehow fixed itself with `reload=False` flag, which was not working earlier. For the autogen's input causing the server to lose connection and refresh, I found one can use ui.run(title='Chat with Autogen Assistant',reload=False, reconnect_timeout=300).  :)

Comment: @AbhishekRai Seems like you to much on the main thread: https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/wiki/FAQs#why-is-my-long-running-function-blocking-ui-updates

Comment: @Falko You are actually right related to the FastAPI... My bad, I was convinced that's built on Flask in background for some reason... Sorry for false information, still I was right about HTTP being stateless. 
It kinda is hard to really understand question, but within comments above I asked what's the problem as OP stated "yes I'd like to preserve the conversation". 
You gave him right pin-point related to the discussion though.